# apportable - insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation: gives error no visible @interface for 'UITableView' declares the selector

Tags: apportable

when building the ios code on the terminal to android (apportable) it gives the following,

error: no visible @interface for 'UITableView' declares the selector 'insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:'

Answer (score 2):

Are you using **Starter** SDK ?
I think **UIKit** is better handled with **Indie** Kit.
I am using Starter at the moment (waiting for my Indie trial) and i can't see any declaration for '**insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:**' in *~/.apportable/SDK/System/UIKit/UITableView.h*

Hope it helps,
Hubert

Edit: [Paul Beusterien](https://stackoverflow.com/users/556617/paul-beusterien) confirmed it is not available in any version of apportable at the moment

Comment: insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation is not yet available in any Apportable edition

Comment: @PaulBeusterien Can you also confirm that there are difference between the implementation of UIKit in the Indie and Starter SDKs?

Comment: For UIKit, there is no difference between the Indie and Starter SDK. A preview of a more complete UIKit implementation is available in the UIKit Developer Preview SDK.